# Shell script help, how to skip a error reporting file?

Tags: shell, tesseract

My current shell script is like this:

```
for i in *.pdf
do
    convert -density 400 $i -depth 8 ${i/pdf/jpg}
done

for j in *.jpg
do
    tesseract -l eng $j ${j/.jpg}
    rm $j
    mv ${j}.txt textfile
done
```

So what it roughly does is, for every pdf files, it converts it to jpg file, and for every jpg files I use tesseract to convert it to a raw text file. THere is no error possible coming from the pdf to jpg conversion, but it is possible for tesseract to report errors such as : "Cancelled repeat of length 0 due to Joined". And my script stops from there...
Is there way to make my script so that it would skip, as soon as it sees some kind of error reporting?? So I dont need to transcribe the corrupted jpg files and want to skip them. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could check `$?` (the return code from the previous command) and exit the script when it is non-zero (eg, failed).

```
[ $? != 0 ] && echo "Failed and died"
# More traditionally
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
  return_val=$?
  echo "Failed with ${return_val} code"
  exit $return_val
fi
```

You can also consolidate your output streams(stdout,stderr) to stdout and take the value

```
r=$(tessaract -l eng $j ... &>/dev/stdout)
```

And `$r` will contain the stderror result.

Alternatively, you can sent the output to another file descriptor you've created via `exec`

Comment: the correct comparison operator to use for non-string comparison in this case would be `-ne` instead of `!=`. Also in the `# More traditionally` case, the exit code has to be saved before `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` because the value of `$?` will be set by the exit code of `[ $? -ne 0]`, so it will always be `0`

Answer (score 0):

tesseract returns error to the command line.

```
for j in *.jpg
do
    tesseract -l eng $j ${j/.jpg}
    [ $? -ne 0 ]  && break
    rm $j
    mv ${j}.txt textfile
done
```

Comment: Could you tell me what [ $? -ne 0] line does?? I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I want it to skip that jpg file and move on to that next one, but my script is still hung up on the error.

Comment: [ space $? -ne 0 space ]  works.  There has to be a space on both sides of [ and ]  What it does:  test the exit (return value from tesseract.  a zero ( 0 ) means "I finished okay" Any other value means "I failed".

Answer (score 0):

If your script is aborting when tesseract fails, then you probably have `set -e` near the top of the script.  If you want the script to abort when tesseract fails, add `set -e` or check that `tesseract` succeeds with either:

```
if ! tesseract -l eng $j ${j/.jpg}; then exit 1; fi
```

or

```
 tesseract -l eng $j ${j/.jpg} || exit 1
```